# Profile cannot be detected after loading Testplan from code

Tags: opentap-proj

I am loading a Test Plan from code with profile, Plan can be loaded and executed with profile. After that, I Close the external app and **I try to open the same tap plan in Tap Editor, Profile is not detected.** Need to select the profile again. Please find the code below that I use to load profile.

```
 Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                InstrumentSettings.SettingsDirectoryRoot = Tap_Settings;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ProfileName))
                {
                    InstrumentSettings.SetSettingsProfile(ProfileGroupName, ProfileName);
                    InstrumentSettings.EnsureSettingsDirectoryExists(ProfileGroupName, true);
                }

                InstrumentSettings.SaveAllCurrentSettings();
            });

            // Set TAP plugin location ,Profile,Log location
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(() => { PluginManager.DirectoriesToSearch.Add(PluginLocation); });
            PluginManager.SearchAsync();
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default profile that is loaded is stored in a file called `CurrentProfile` in `%TAP_PATH%\Settings\Bench`. There is not an API to update it. But you can edit the file. The only text in the file should be the Profile name.